# Publishing a message to Kafka running inside docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am running Kafka inside docker container. I start my container using the following command

```
docker run --rm -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 -p 8081:8081 --env 
ADVERTISED_HOST=\`docker-machine ip \\`docker-machine active\\`` --env 
ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -v  
/Users/abhishek.srivastava/MyProjects/KafkaTest/target/scala-2.11:/app 
-it --  name kafka spotify/kafka bash
```

I have written a simple program which I can copy inside the container and execute it and it works perfectly.

```
object KafkaProducerString {

  def SendStringMessage(msg: String) : Unit = {
    val inputRecord = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test", null, msg)
    val producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = CreateProducerString
    val rm = producer.send(inputRecord).get(10, SECONDS)
    println(s"offset: ${rm.offset()} partition: ${rm.partition()} topic: ${rm.topic()}")
    producer.close()
  }

  private def CreateProducerString: KafkaProducer[String, String] = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("batch.size", "0")
    props.put("client.id", "1")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    producer
  }
}
```

But if I run this same program from outside the container (from my mac). [I replace the "localhost" with the output from `docker-machine ip`]

I get this error

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting for 10000 ms.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting for 10000 ms.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25)
    at com.abhi.KafkaProducerString$.SendStringMessage(KafkaProducerString.scala:23)
    at com.abhi.KafkaMain$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(KafkaMain.scala:19)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at com.abhi.KafkaMain$.main(KafkaMain.scala:17)
    at com.abhi.KafkaMain.main(KafkaMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

My understanding was that for a kafka producer to be remote the only ports I need to open are 2181 (zookeeper) and 9092 (kafka) and you can see that I have opened these.

But still The same program when executed outside the container times out but works when inside the container (with localhost).

Edit:: Based on the suggestions below, I tried the following

```
docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:2181:2181 -p 127.0.0.1:9092:9092 -p 
127.0.0.1:8081:8081 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine 
active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -v 
/Users/abhishek.srivastava/MyProjects/KafkaTest/target/scala-2.11:/app -it --
name kafka kafka_9.0 bash
```

and

```
docker run --rm -p 0.0.0.0:2181:2181 -p 0.0.0.0:9092:9092 -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8081 
--env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env 
ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -v 
/Users/abhishek.srivastava/MyProjects/KafkaTest/target/scala-2.11:/app -it --
name kafka kafka_9.0 bash
```

But these did not solve the problem. I get exactly the same issue

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. did you get it resolved?

Comment: I gave up  :) will try sometime again when I have time. check the solution below. let me know if it works :)

Comment: I am using wurstmeister kafka docker. Everything works inside docker but my code for producer/consumer that is on host machine is not able to connect to the kafka broker. I am troubleshooting this if something comes up i will let you know

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. Kindly update if you had found any solution to this. Or if any alternative approach that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind your docker container to local machine. This can be done by using docker run as:

```
docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:2181:2181 -p 127.0.0.1:9092:9092 -p 127.0.0.1:8081:8081 ....
```

Alternatively you can use docker run with bind IP:

```
docker run --rm -p 0.0.0.0:2181:2181 -p 0.0.0.0:9092:9092 -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8081 .....
```

If you want to make docker container routable on your network you can use:

```
docker run --rm -p <private-IP>:2181:2181 -p <private-IP>:9092:9092 -p <private-IP>:8081:8081 ....
```

Or finally you can go for not containerising your network interface by using:

```
docker run --rm -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 -p 8081:8081 --net host ....
```

Comment: I tried the first two and they did not resolve my problem

Comment: Did you expose the concerned ports in your Dockerfile?

Comment: here is the docker file https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/blob/master/kafka/Dockerfile

Comment: You will have to expose port 8081 which you are trying to bind first of all. Also check whether docker container is running using docker ps. And make sure if docker container is running you are able to telnet on your host on exposed ports which you have bound to host machine.

Comment: tried it ... same problem. I wonder if you can download my project from github and then try to see if you can run it (from outside docker container) https://github.com/abhitechdojo/KafkaTest

Answer (score 0):

While I myself am facing the similar problem, I can try to explain this behavior.

Kafka producer will lookup for partition leader from Zookeeper, before publishing the record to the Topic. Zookeeper will be having the leader host entry as marked by the Kafka server, which is running inside of a Docker container.

Due to this fact, the IP marked by the server will be the Docker internal IP, instead of the host IP. Which of course will not be resolvable from the client machine and hence timing out.

A probable solution could be, is to have `advertised.host.name` set to the host IP of the Docker machine. However, this will introduce another problem (as I faced!)

Broker metadata fetch by the server will start failing now. This is because now the Zookeeper entry has the host IP, which is not resolvable from inside of the container. As a consequence any consumer application would now start getting `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` warnings.

This is a deadlock situation and the solution depends mainly on the *host resolution strategy* employed. I would like to know how people would suggest to go about here.

Edit : Finally we used host networking [--net=host] and used node static IP to get around the problem.

Comment: You have probably stated a problem I've experienced